# CSV file row incrementing

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

Currently I am working on a CSV file program where I have to partition the CSV file into non overlapping parts (row-wise), but should not create any extra files in the disk.

Currently I am using this program to read particular parts of the CSV file row-wise:

```
def dataFromFile(fname):
    record = []
    count=0
    with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
         reader = csv.reader(f)
         for row in reader:
             while '' in row:
                   row.remove('')
             count+=1
             record.append(row)
    print count
    return record[0:4]
```

Here I am able to read the rows within the range 0-4.
But is there a possibility to automate this i.e can we without giving that range manually everytime read the next 4 rows and so-on till the end of CSV file?

The CSV file contains:

```
apple   beer    rice    chicken
apple   beer    rice    
apple   beer        
apple   mango       
milk    beer    rice    chicken
milk    beer    rice    
milk    beer        
milk    mango
```

Comment: Could you give a specific example of the input CSV file and the expected result?

Comment: What is the handling of `''` supposed to mean?

Comment: @mkrieger1 ' ' are the empty spaces in the list . The example csv file contains transaction data of a market without any labels or headers.

Comment: Is there really an empty line after each record? And are the fields really not *comma-separated*? If this is the case, you need to specify `delimiter=' '` argument to `csv.reader`, and you need to discard empty lines.

Comment: @mkrieger1 There are no empty lines after each record. In the first row there are 4 items and in the second there are 3, because of this i was getting empty space with ' ' in the output. Hence i used the While loop to remove them.

Comment: @klashxx Sorry was a busy a bit. I found out a different answer on my own and am trying to implement it into my code. Your suggestion was helpfull thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`yield`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators):

```
def dataFromFile(fname):
    record = []
    print'Opening the file is executed once'
    count = 0
    with open(fname) as f:
        for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter=' '):
            count += 1
            fields = [field for field in row if field]
            if fields:
                record.append(fields)
            if len(record) == 4:
                print 'Last yielded row:', count
                yield(record)
                record = []
    if record:
        yield record
```

And the *call*:

```
for row in dataFromFile('your.csv'):
   print row
```

**From the interpreter**

```
>>> import csv
>>> 
>>> def dataFromFile(fname):
    record = []
    print 'Opening the file is executed once'
    count = 0
    with open(fname) as f:
        for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter=' '):
            count += 1

            fields = [field for field in row if field]
            if fields:
                record.append(fields)
            if len(record) == 4:
                print 'Last yielded row:', count
                yield(record)
                record = []
    if record:
        yield record 
... 
>>> for row in dataFromFile('your.csv'):
...     print row
... 
Opening the file is executed once
Last yielded row: 4
[['apple', 'beer', 'rice', 'chicken'], ['apple', 'beer', 'rice'], ['apple', 'beer'], ['apple', 'mango']]
Last yielded row: 8
[['milk', 'beer', 'rice', 'chicken'], ['milk', 'beer', 'rice'], ['milk', 'beer'], ['milk', 'mango']]
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I dont want to read the first 4 rows again after reading it once.I am using those first 4 rows as a input to a program. I  want to exclude them, read the next 4 rows,input them into that program and do the same for the next number of rows.

Comment: I am not that familiar with generators. I will look into it. Thank you.

Comment: record = [ ] makes the record as a list. But yield doesnt work with list.

Comment: It works, see my edited answer,  the *prints* may help you to fully understand it